# PHP - Pass string as object array's index

Tags: php, arrays, object

I would like to get array value after passing it's index as a string.

```
$array = $user->challengeWeek;
$arrayIndex = 'challenge->languages[0]->title';

foreach($array as $a){
    echo $a->$arrayIndex . '<br/>;
}
```

Any tip for this?

Comment: `->` indicates objects. Make sure you understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tackle one element of the path at a time, you cannot access it directly. An `array_reduce` does very nicely here:

```
function getValueFromPath($o, array $path) {
    return array_reduce(
        $path,
        function ($o, $key) { return is_array($o) ? $o[$key] : $o->$key; },
        $o
    );
}

$path = ['challenge', 'languages', 0, 'title'];

foreach ($array as $a) {
    echo getValueFromPath($a, $path);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It gets me an error: `Property [0] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: Then the object you're feeing it and the path you're trying to access don't match.